# Shiny Warning: Error in ==: comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types Stack trace (innermost first):

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I am having some problem with my code, I am trying to run this code, but I am am getting the error:

> Warning: Error in ==: comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types Stack trace (innermost first):

The problem seems to be in the `if-then` function for the `renderText`, and I am not able to figure out what is wrong here. I have made it reactive. What I want to make sure is that the number of municipalities(/reservoirs) and the number in the csv file match.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Information required for the model",
               sliderInput("Reservoirs", label = h3("Total Number of Reservoirs"), 
                           min = 1, max = 50, 
                           value = 10),
               sliderInput("Municipalities", label = h3("Total Number of Municipalities Served by the Reservoirs"), 
                           min = 1, max = 150, 
                           value = 15)

      ),
      tabPanel("Uploading files and other information",
               fileInput("ResName", "What are the names of the reservoirs?",
                         accept = c(
                           "text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv")
               ),
               fileInput("MunicipName", "What are the names of the municipalities?",
                         accept = c(
                           "text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv")
               )
               ),
      tabPanel("Summary of Inputs", tableOutput("Summary_Page_1a"), tableOutput("Summary_Page_1b"), tableOutput("Summary_Page_1c")),
      tabPanel("Summary of csv files", tableOutput("Summary_Page_2"))

    )))

server <- function(input, output) {
  names_of_reservoirs<-reactive(nrow(input$ResName))
  names_of_municipalities<-reactive(nrow(input$MunicipName))
  output$Summary_Page_1a<-renderText({(paste0("There are ", 
                                              input$Reservoirs, 
                                              " reservoirs <br> Serving ", 
                                              input$Municipalities, 
                                              " municipalities."
  ))
  })

  output$Summary_Page_1b<- renderText({if ((names_of_reservoirs)==input$Reservoirs){
    " "
  }else{
    "ERROR! The number of reservoirs and the number of reservoir names do not match"}
  })
  output$Summary_Page_1c<- renderText({if ((names_of_municipalities)==input$Municipalities){
    " "
  }else{
    "ERROR! The number of Municipalities and the number of muncipality names do not match"}
  })                                  



}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2):

Reactive expressions must be called to access their values. That is, `names_of_reservoirs()` and `names_of_municipalities()` instead of `names_of_reservoirs` and `names_of_municipalities`.

Once you fix that, also be sure to validate that the values aren't `NULL` before using them in `==` comparisons.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this help. I realised my error in this, but I was not able to run it still. I am sending you the response in an answer, if you could help. Thanks!!!